# Why are these functions entering an infinite loop?

Tags: c++

```
using u32 = unsigned int;

Byte FetchByte(u32 Cycles, Mem& memory) {
        Byte Data = memory[PC];
        PC++;
        Cycles--;
        return Data;
    }
void Execute(u32 Cycles, Mem& memory) {
    while (Cycles > 0) {
        Byte Instruction = FetchByte(Cycles, memory);
        (void)Instruction;
    }
}
```

I am calling the execute function as .Execute(2, mem);
it enters an infinite loop where Cycles arent being substracted, ive entered the debugger already it doesnt sustract it isnt a matter of time

Comment: Because `Cycles` is passed to `FetchByte` by value, i.e. as a _copy_, so decrementation is performed on a copy, not on a variable in `Execute` – the value of the `Cycles` variable in `Execute` remains constant.

Comment: `using u32 = unsigned int;` - oh no there goes another fairy.

Comment: Using `uint32_t` from cstdint would be safer (portable) except if you're 100% sure that your code will always be run for a target that have `sizeof(unsigned int) == 32`.

Comment: @Fareanor: A 32 byte `int` on your platform?! Respect.

Comment: I would replace your custom type U32 with uint32_t. The term 'unsigned int' may not always represent a 32-bit type, despite the U32 name suggesting so. The width of an 'unsigned int' is influenced by the Data Model, where, according to the **C++ Standard**, it is "at least" 16 bits; in specific models such as **LP32**, it is 16 bits, while in **ILP32**, **LLP64**, and **LP64**, it is 32 bits.

Comment: `cycles` is not used in `FetchByte` it is in use just in `Execute`. There is no need to pass it and the correct way is to decrement it in `Execute`.

Comment: @Bathsheba Ooops XD I wrote too fast ahah I meant `4` (32 bits, assuming CHAR_BIT is 8) XD (Or maybe I have a an alien computer...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FetchByte` takes `Cycles` by value, so it has its own copy of this object. The statement `Cycles--` is thus pointless.

If you want `Cycles--` to also take effect in `Execute`, it must be passed by reference:

```cpp
Byte FetchByte(u32& Cycles, Mem& memory) { /* ... */ }
```

This way, `FetchByte` does not have its own copy of `Cycles`, but it refers to the object in the caller. `Cycles--` would thus decrement the object in the caller. This is also called "action at a distance".

#### Note on compiler warnings

If you are using clang and enable compiler warnings, you should also receive a warning about this. Unfortunately, GCC and MSVC don't detect this.

```cpp
// warning: parameter 'X' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-parameter]
void Decrement(int X) {
    X--;
}
```

*See [live example at Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/aTd5qPr41)*

#### See Also

- [How should I pass objects to functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2139224/5740428) [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)
- [What's the difference between passing by reference vs. passing by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/373419/5740428) [language-agnostic](/questions/tagged/language-agnostic)

Comment: As a side note, you might also want to consider better naming (what does `Cycles` mean - "number of Bytes to be read" pehaps? Then naming the variable accordingly might make the code easier to read), the reason *why* you are passing Cycles to the function `FetchByte` (does it need to know or could you contain&handle the logic in the calling function) and the fact that you are using `PC` (which seems to be some kind of global variable?)